# Bison error recovery suggestion

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison

I'm trying to integrate error recovery in my grammar. From the bison manual, the simplest error recovery would be skip the current line. But in my flex file, I have no action regarding the newline so the parser would not know about it. So I want the parser to ignore everything until it encounters a semicolon in case of an error.

I have the following grammar:

```
start : program;

program : program unit 
    | unit
    ;

unit : var_declaration
     | func_declaration
     | func_definition
     ;

func_declaration : type_specifier ID LPAREN parameter_list RPAREN SEMICOLON
        | type_specifier ID LPAREN RPAREN SEMICOLON
        ;

func_definition : type_specifier ID LPAREN parameter_list RPAREN compound_statement
        | type_specifier ID LPAREN RPAREN compound_statement
        ;               


parameter_list  : parameter_list COMMA type_specifier ID
        | parameter_list COMMA type_specifier
        | type_specifier ID
        | type_specifier
        ;


compound_statement : LCURL statements RCURL
            | LCURL RCURL
            ;

var_declaration : type_specifier declaration_list SEMICOLON
         ;

type_specifier  : INT
        | FLOAT
        | VOID
        ;

declaration_list : declaration_list COMMA ID
          | declaration_list COMMA ID LTHIRD CONST_INT RTHIRD
          | ID
          | ID LTHIRD CONST_INT RTHIRD
          ;

statements : statement
       | statements statement
       ;

statement : var_declaration
      | expression_statement
      | compound_statement
      | FOR LPAREN expression_statement expression_statement expression RPAREN statement
      | IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement
      | IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement ELSE statement
      | WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN statement
      | PRINTLN LPAREN ID RPAREN SEMICOLON
      | RETURN expression SEMICOLON
      ;

expression_statement    : SEMICOLON         
            | expression SEMICOLON 
            ;

variable : ID       
     | ID LTHIRD expression RTHIRD 
     ;

 expression : logic_expression  
       | variable ASSIGNOP logic_expression     
       ;

logic_expression : rel_expression   
         | rel_expression LOGICOP rel_expression    
         ;

rel_expression  : simple_expression 
        | simple_expression RELOP simple_expression 
        ;

simple_expression : term 
          | simple_expression ADDOP term 
          ;

term :  unary_expression
     |  term MULOP unary_expression
     ;

unary_expression : ADDOP unary_expression  
         | NOT unary_expression 
         | factor 
         ;

factor  : variable 
    | ID LPAREN argument_list RPAREN
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN
    | CONST_INT 
    | CONST_FLOAT
    | variable INCOP 
    | variable DECOP
    ;

argument_list : arguments
              |
              ;

arguments : arguments COMMA logic_expression
          | logic_expression
          ;
```

I'm currently working on the following input:

```
int main(){
    int a[2],c,i,j ; float c;
    a[2.5]=1;
    i=2.3
    j=2%3.7;    
    a=4;
    func(a);
    b=8;
    return 0;
}
```

When the parser encounters `i = 2.3`, it won't stop parsing but rather continue doing so after reporting a syntax error.

Based on the grammar, where should I put my error production so that the parser can continue parsing without any conflict ? And possibly shed some light on other syntax errors like missing a RPAREN or Curly braces ? How should I approach to add the error production for a given grammar ?

Comment: `statement` seems like a good candidate. Add a rule like `error SEMICOLON`. It should be pretty obvious if you spend some time [with the error-recovery documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html).

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. I read the link you gave. Actually ``statement`` came to my mind at the very first. But I was working on something like : `` int a[2.5],....`` so I added an error production on the ``var_declaration``, and then added one in the statement. Seeing the list of 19 conflicts, I lost my mind and didn't think clearly to remove the error production from the ``var_declaration``. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: After adding an error rule to the ``statement``, the parser parses the code as follows:
`int main(){
int a[2],c,i,j;
float c;
a[2.5]=1;
3.7
a=4;
func;
b=8;
return 0;
}`

should 3.7 be there ?

Comment: That is not a parse. It is a list of tokens. You might try explaining how you got that list and what you think it means.

Comment: For the given grammar and a given input, I have to print the "code" that matches a certain grammar rule. I have a ``SymbolInfo`` class. In my ``.y`` file, I have declared ``YYSTYPE`` as ``SymbolInfo*``. When I pass the tokens from lex to bison ( ``yylval`` as a ``SymbolInfo*`` ), the parser catches it and from their value and constructs a ``SymbolInfo*`` for the non-terminal.

Comment: Something like this, for the grammar rule, `var_declaration : type_specifier declaration_list SEMICOLON;` the action would be, `string s = $1 -> getSymbolName() + $2 -> getSymbolName() + ";" ; SymbolInfo* s = new SymbolInfo(s,"dummy_type"); $$ = s;` and the I print ``$$`` on a log file. This goes on in a bottom-up fashion until the parser reaches ``program`` rule.

Comment: How about handling error recovery in case of function declaration and definition?

Case 1: `int a(int b) int main(){ return 0;}` , function ``a`` is missing a semicolon at the end of its declaration.

Case 2: `int a(int b) } int main() {return 0;}` , function ``a`` is missing a LCURL in its definition.

In both cases, I want to parse the rest of the input. How can I do so?

Comment: I tried by adding ``| error NEWLINE { yyerrok; } ; `` to the ``func_declaration`` rule in the grammar. But it doesn't seem to work.